# PDE characteristic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm having trouble with this IVP PDE problem.

$uu_x +yu_y=x$

with initial conditions $x=s$, $y=s$, and $u=2s$

I get $dx/dt=u$, $dy/dt=y$, and $du/dt=x$

From there I get $x = ut+s$, $y=se^t$, and $u=xt+2s$

I tried to solve for t and s in terms of x and y then express $u$ in these terms but every time I try to solve for t and s the formulas end up incredibly messy and don't work out. Am I setting this up correctly? I tried looking up similar problems but they are always simpler examples that work out or they solve the question in a different method we haven't learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$uu_x+yu_y=x$$
Solving thanks to the method of characteristics :

The set of ODEs for the characteristics equations is 
$\quad \frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{x}$

From $\quad \frac{dx}{u}\frac{du}{x}\quad\to\quad xdx=udu\quad\to\quad u^2-x^2=c_1\quad$  which is a first characteristic equation.

From $\quad \frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dy}{y}\quad\to\quad \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+c_1}}=\frac{dy}{y}\quad\to\quad \ln|\sqrt{x^2+c_1}+x|=\ln|y|+$constant.

$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+c_1}+x}{y}=c_2 \quad\to\quad \frac{u+x}{y}=c_2\quad$ is a second characteristic equation.

The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of an implicit equation is :
$$\Phi\left((u^2-x^2)\:,\:\left(\frac{u+x}{y}\right)\right)=0$$
any differentiable function $\Phi$ of two variables.

An equivalent form is :
$$\frac{u+x}{y}=F(u^2-x^2)$$
any differentiable function $F$.

An implicit form of general solution of the PDE is :
$$u=-x+yF(u^2-x^2)$$

The function $F$ has to be determined according to the conditions specified in the wording of the question : $\quad x=y=\frac{u}{2}=s$

$2s=-s+sF((2s)^2-s^2) \quad\to\quad 3=F(3s^2)\quad\to\quad F$ is a constant function $=3$.

According to the specified conditions the particular solution of the PDE is :
$$u=-x+3y$$

Final check :

$u_x=-1\quad u_y=3\quad uu_x+yu_y=-(-x+3y)+3y=x\quad$ OK for the PDE.

$x=y=s \quad\to\quad u=-s+3s=2s\quad$ OK for the specified conditions.

Comment: Could you use this same method without needing to solve for $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+c_1}}$? In order to integrate that, you need to do a large amount of trig substitutions.

Comment: I see, $\frac{dx + du}{u+x}=\frac{dy}{y}\Rightarrow \frac{u+x}{y}=C_2$ avoids this problem.

Comment: OK. This is simpler and leads to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

$uu_x + uu_y=x$ (this is Lagrange's first order linear pde ) hence the subsidary equation is :
$$\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{x
}$$
First $$\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{du}{x} \Rightarrow  x\ dx=u\ du \Rightarrow u^2-x^2=C_1$$

Second $$\frac{dx - du}{u-x}=\frac{dy}{y}\Rightarrow y(u-x)=C_2$$

So the general solution is  :$$y(u-x)=f(u^2-x^2)$$
If $x=y=s $ and u =2s which implies that the particular solution is :
$$y(u-x)=3 \Rightarrow u(x,y)=x+\frac{C}{y}$$

To make sure that this is a right solution check :
$$u_x=1  $$$$u_y=\frac{-C}{y^2}$$
Finally$$uu_x+yu_y=x+\frac{C}{y}+y(\frac{-C}{y^2})=x$$
More precisely : "C=0" that's why i left C in the particular solution it doesn't matter .

Comment: Has this answer been accepted?

Comment: Ah, you could have done $\frac{dx + du}{u+x}=\frac{dy}{y}\Rightarrow \frac{u+x}{y}=C_2$ which matches the first answer.